# Could not load file or assembly HTMLAgilityPack. Installed from Nuget

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, html-agility-pack

```
{"Could not load file or assembly 'HtmlAgilityPack, Version=1.4.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bd319b19eaf3b43a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"HtmlAgilityPack, Version=1.4.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bd319b19eaf3b43a"}
```

I am very new to c# (couple weeks of goofing around). Installed this library from nuget as it was suggested on many forums and websites.

It works as expected in development. However when publishing it can't seem to find it. Other libraries are loaded just fine. The `HtmlAgilityPack.dll` is with all the others in the deploy folder.

I have also tried downloading older version 1.4.6, 1.4.0 and even adding reference directly to the dll

Comment: if you go to the bin/release folder of your solution and execute ytour exe it throws the same exception?

Comment: @Gusman no. The bin/debug does throw the exception

Comment: are you sure you're recompiling the solution? try to clean it and then recompile.

Comment: @Gusman tried recompiling and cleaning it couple times. Delete system32?

Comment: erhm... what?? system32??? sorry but I got lost, if you mean to delete the system32 folder of windows, NO!!!! never!!! you will break your s.o. Check the compilation dates of your exe to check it's being recompiled, I can't think in any motive to it work in debug but not in release if they're the same project... are you obfuscation by any chance the output?

Comment: What do you mean publishing it? What kind of application is this? Is this web?

Comment: @Gusman I was joking about system32

Comment: @Gusman So when i do a build, it compiles the files to bin/debug and when i publish it, it goes to big/deploy? what about the app.publish folder?

Comment: nonono, compile your program as release and check the bin/release folder

Comment: @BonMacalindong its a visual windows application. Does a search on a server and then parses the results. Publishing as in build -> publish

Comment: Moral of the story here, is that all dlls used by your application should be in your bin folder.